# play audio on jsp file in my project

Tags: javascript, jsp

I am making a game and want to play audio from my jsp page.
I have tried to do this using various solutions but none of them were helpful to me.

I tried this way and some others. What did I not try yet?

```js
playSound('game_start_sound');

function playSound(id){

 var audio = document.getElementById(id);

  audio.play();
 // alert("played");


}
```

```html
 <audio id="game_start_sound">
   <source src="http://localhost:8080/firstproject/sound/gamestart.mp3" type='audio/mpeg; codecs="mp3"'></embed>
   </audio>

 <audio id="game_start_sound">
   <embed src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/sound/gamestart.mp3" type='audio/mpeg; codecs="mp3"'></embed>
   </audio>

 <audio id="game_start_sound">
   <embed src="http://localhost:8080/firstproject/sound/gamestart.mp3" type='audio/mpeg; codecs="mp3"'></embed>
   </audio>

 <embed id="game_start_sound">
   <source src="http://localhost:8080/firstproject/sound/gamestart.mp3" type='audio/mpeg; codecs="mp3"'></embed>
   </embed>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why using `<embed>`? Use `<source>` instead

```
 <audio id="game_start_sound">
       <source  src="http://localhost:8080/firstproject/sound/gamestart.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></source>
       <source  src="http://localhost:8080/firstproject/sound/gamestart.ogg" type="audio/ogg"></source>
 </audio>
```

For firefox you need to add ogg files.Find [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats) full chart of audio type supported by each browser

Comment: i also tried the same in my first line of code and it is in jsp page.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have the wrong ID. Try this:

```
playSound('game_start_sound');

function playSound(id){
    var audio = document.getElementById(id);
    audio.play();   
}

<audio id="game_start_sound">
   <source src="http://localhost:8080/firstproject/sound/gamestart.mp3" type='audio/mpeg; codecs="mp3"'></source>
</audio>
```

Comment: ya thanks but it my mistake to write the incorrect sample question but problem is same with the correct id.